# Getting angular-cli to copy over my server.js file when using ng build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I can't figure out in the documentation how to get this to work. Is there a place in the angular-cli.json file or anywhere else in my application where I can specify that I want my node server.js file to copy over to my dist folder as is without combining with any other js file, so I can run it after ng build completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the newer cli version (>beta.18 I think), there is an 'assets' property in the angular-cli.json. There you can add specific files that you want copied. Rather than having to stick it all in the assets folder. 
Example:

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.png",
        "server.js",
        "routes",
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this without messing with build configs is putting it the `assests` folder

Try putting it in the `/src/assets` folder of the Angular-Cli project, then run the `ng build` and you should see the `/dist/assets` folder with your file in it and you can just path out to it.

Comment: In the latest versions the `public` folder is actually called `assets` by default.

Comment: Thanks this worked great. Easier than messing with config files yes.

Comment: Haha thats how I do it when I want to include some file. Glad to help out!